# while function doesnt work with CSV file colum

Tags: python, csv

So for a project I'm writing a code, but it doesnt work like I want it to work. If a value if between 2 known values it should return a word.
I tried some little things but it didnt fix it.
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pygef.gef import ParseGEF

# Read *.gef file
gef = ParseGEF("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.Gef")

gef.df.to_csv("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF")
bestand = pd.read_csv("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF", usecols=['friction_number' , 'depth', 'elevation_with_respect_to_NAP'])
print (bestand)


wrijvingsgetal = pd.read_csv ("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF", usecols=['friction_number'])
print (wrijvingsgetal)
```

This gives me a return of all the "friction_numbers" inside of my file:

```
 friction_number
```

0           1.498638

1           0.943396

2           0.909091

3           1.172708

4           1.585014

..               ...

329         0.693328

330         0.665844

331         0.646598

332         0.626465

333         0.605465

The problem is that if I try to search between two values (example: 0,2 < wrijvingsgetal < 0,6), it just sends an error. The error is: `'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: "the `wrijvingsgetal['friction_number']` is a column out of my CSV file" - according to the error message, `wrijvingsgetal` is a single floating-point number. What does the CSV file look like and how are you reading it?

Answer (score 0):

The error `'float' object is not subscriptable` , means you are trying to access a float value's using the 'n'th character.

like if `a[0] = 2.2 , a[1] = 5.5`  you cannot access third character in that float value like a string or a list. For Eg `a[0][1] = 2`, this is not allowed.

Your question is not very clear to elaborate on your answer. however given you want to  read values from a CSV file and print "gravel" for a specific value use this

```
import pandas as pd
col_list = ["Value"]
df = pd.read_csv("sample_file.csv", usecols=col_list)
for i in range(0,df.shape[0])
    if( 0.2 < df.Value[0] < 0.6 ) print("Gravel");
```

Given that your column name in csv file is "Value", which is in this form

```
name,Value
aa,0.2
bb,0.7
cc,0.8
dd,0.3
```

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your reply. Its kinda hard to describe things right if you have no idea of what you are doing and if a part of the code isnt in english. But what you said didnt work, it just gave the exact same error.

Comment: Can you print `wrijvingsgetal['friction_number']` once and let us know the output so that we could trouble shoot it better. Also please post the part of code where you are reading the csv file

Comment: Hi, I edited the original post. Is it clearer now?